# VBA for loop takes too long

Tags: vba, excel

Just starting out on VBA, and my code is painfully slow. I have a number of workbooks on a network drive, each with several worksheets. I am trying to fetch data from a number of non-contiguous ranges in each worksheet to a pre-designed worksheet, using the following code:

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
    'retrieve value
    '// code
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function

Sub UpdateModel1()

    sheet = "blah blah"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Outputs
    destRow = 31            'destination row
    destCol = 6             'destination column
    srcRow = 50             'source row

    For C = 23 To 31        'loop through source columns
        ref = Cells(srcRow, C).Address
        Cells(destRow, destCol) = GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
        destCol = destCol + 1
    Next C

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

However, using a nested `for` loop in the sub procedure takes way too long. Any suggestions on how to improve this code? PS: this is an amateur's code, and I am just looking for something that does the work decently.

Comment: Maybe the GetValue slows it down as the iterations of the loop are not many. Did you try without GetValue to see how much faster it executes?

Comment: I don't understand this: `ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)` arg is not defined anywhere, you then don't use the variables you pass into the function. When you run it, do you get any result other than "="?

Comment: It looks like your "GetValue" function opens a workbook and extracts a single value then closes it. This is an expensive process. Not to mention you are doing this over a network connection. Even more expensive. Now it's in a loop. No wonder it's so slow. If this is not a routine process you might just copy the files to your local machine. Also, if possible, you might copy more than a single value to your destination file while the source file is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of what you are trying to do:

```
Sub TestGetSheetValue()
    MsgBox GetSheetValue("N:\Tax Documents\", "Tax Stuff.xlsx", "Sheet1", "R1C3")
End Sub


Function GetSheetValue(strPath As String, strFile As String, strSheet As String, strCellRef As String)
    GetSheetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & strPath & "[" & strFile & "]" & strSheet & "'!" & strCellRef)
End Function
```

Obviously change what you pass into the function for your needs, note the address is R1C1 format.

The strSheet is the sheet name, not the sheet index.

Make sure you have a trailing `\` on the path

Finally, try not to use names like file, path and sheet for variable names.